# What are the packages for Linux Libraries?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, rpm, yum

I am trying to install an application on CentOS 7 that needs several libraries:

```
libcryptopp.so.6
libdns_sd.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
```

Where can I get these libraries? Is there a yum repo that contains them? Are they standard? If so, what package(s) do I install to get these libraries?

Someone please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this command for every file that you need:

```
yum provides fileName
```

You will need to run:

```
yum install avahi-compat-libdns_sd libstdc++  cryptopp
```

For last package, you need to have epel-release install and enabled.

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: EPEL : 1) $ `cd Downloads/` ... 2) # `yum install  epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` ...   https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm ...

Comment: Thanks. Added this.